# How to get app name programatically in native script

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to save some files on my local File storage So, I'm doing Something like below

```
var folder_name = "abcde/" + viewModel.dir_path;
                const documents = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.documents();
                documents._path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                const folder = documents.getFolder(folder_name);
                var file = fileSystemModule.path.join(folder._path, this.pdf_url.split("/").pop());
                var url = this.pdf_url;

                httpModule.getFile(url, file).then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    Toast.makeText(`${result._name} is succesfully downloaded in ${folder_name}`).show();

                }, function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                });
```

the only problem is the hardcoded value `abcde/` I want it to be `app name`. whatever the app name is it should take that name.

I don't find any ways to read app name programatically. I need this to Android I'm not interested in IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this is one could be the answer. but still this is not a proper way

```
const documents = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.currentApp();
console.log(documents); --> "/data/data/org.nativescript.app_name/files/app"
var str = documents;
var arr = str.split("/")[3];
console.log(arr.split(".")[2]); ---> app_name
```

Comment: whatever may be, this gives a work around So that i can achieve what i need. I mark this as answer currently.

Comment: The string after third delimiter necessarily not to be the app name.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can set the app name for the application in `strings.xml`, for example:

```
<string name="app_name">"App_Name"</string>
```

Then whenever you want to reuse the app name, you can use the `getString` method with its name in the application.

Comment: where is that file .

Comment: Find it from App_Resource/Android/res/values/strings.xml

Comment: Then just create it yourself : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource. After that, to set the app name using the strings value, you need to edit AndroidManifest.xml, then add `android:label="@string/app_name"` into the <activity> tag

Comment: I think the above answer works for both ios and android. but what u are saying is only for android right.

Comment: Same for iOS, you can set the app name in Info.plist & you can retrieve it from Bundle too. The above answer works for both but as you said, it's not the proper way. If you want a proper way that works for both platforms, then consider to develop a plugin that use the proper way for each platform (for example, there's already a plugin to get the app version: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-appversion)

Comment: Then in xml how to give two names for a single label. if i follow this. Since Ios and Android will be separate right.